# Where has the @ gone ?

Tags: support, comment-notification

I started my comment on [Marty Isaacs' answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/230460/an-inequality-for-the-minimal-number-of-generators-of-a-finite-group) with "@Marty Isaacs". But after saving the comment, the @... disappeared. What's the reason for this behavoir of the system ?

Comment: Sure. When you are addressing the author of a post, it's not necessary to use the @; the author will get notified automatically, and in fact the software strips the @ way. If you want to address another party who has participated in the thread, then you need the @.

Comment: @Todd Trimble: In my opinion this feature (i.e. stripping the @) is confusing and useless. But anyway, thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: Tangentially, it is in general better not to leave a space when forming the notifying string, which is also what auto-complete does. The reason is that the system searches for the first space after the @ and matches the string in between (slightly tweaked) to the start of potentially meant user names.  For example for the purpose of notification "@Todd Trimble" and "@Todd Leason" are identical. Both will notify the last user in the conversation whose display name starts with Todd (or something equivalent to it).`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the full details on how comment notifications work on [meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

For this instance, the `@` wasn't necessary since the OP is always notified when someone comments. The main reason for this is that [only the first `@` ping](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/should-we-discourage-the-use-of-multiple-redundant-username-pings-in-comments/2615#2615) actually works in any comment; subsequent `@` symbols are either blocked or ignored. So unnecessary pings to the OP, especially potentially blocking ones, are automatically removed.