# Is linking to comments possible?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

I vaguely remember seeing links to comments somewhere, was it a dream or it is indeed doable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a link to a comment, simply click on the timestamp next to it. (If it is your comment, be careful not to click on "Delete" by mistake.)

For example, this is a [link to the first comment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4763/is-linking-to-comments-possible#comment24196_4764) posted below this answer.

It is possible to get link to some specific comment also from other places where you might see that comment. (Such as user's activity tab, your inbox, etc.) But the above method gives a possibility to get link to any comment you see on the page wich a post - which is, I'd guess, where you'd encounter comments most often.

- Mathematics Meta: [How to link to a comment?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1816)
- Meta Stack Exchange: [Direct Link to a Comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5436)

About linking to a specific *answer*: [How do I link to a MO answer?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1885)

Comment: I will add here at least one comment - so that you can test whether this really works.

Comment: Many thanks! Yes, it works.

Comment: By some reason I cannot do `@MartinSleziak` here, could it be related to the fact that you linked to it??

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I'd look at "[Where has the @ gone ?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2726)" and "[How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019)" for possible explanations when `@username` is automatically removed by the software. But I don't see how *linking to the comment* could influence that.

Comment: Oh I see, I did not pay attention that I am responding to the author of the answer, not to a commenter.

Comment: Sometimes I want to link to a comment inside another comment, so I strip away as much cruft as possible.  Often the copied link includes `noredirect=1` or whatever, and that can go away.  I've noticed in fact that the slug can go, too: `https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4763/is-linking-to-comments-possible#comment24200_4764` can be shortened just to `https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4763#comment24200_4764`.  However, this seems to break when there are multiple pages of answers.  In that case, what is the minimum I need to keep to link to the correct comment?

Comment: @LSpice I [tried a few variants](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19138/conversation/shortening-links-to-comments) and found out that if I get a comment link *from an answer*, the link no longer works after changing the part of URL which contains the title. I'd guess this could be considered a bug, since this might cause links obtained from a timestamp to stop working after an edit to the title. Let me know, whether you plan to post something about this on [meta.se] - if not, I can post the bug report about this issue.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, [re](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4763/is-linking-to-comments-possible/4764#comment24322_4764), I haven't done enough experimentation to figure out what works and what doesn't, so, if you are in a position to file a proper bug report, then I'd certainly be grateful if you could.

Comment: @LSpice I got a suggestion on [meta.se] to use the links in this format if I need to save the number of characters: `https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/2259`. You can check that it [goes to a comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/2259). This was suggested in rene's comment under my post: [Links to comments when the title has been edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358749).

Comment: @MartinSleziak, cool!  [That](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/24328) link appears to be edited down from `https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2340/what-is-the-first-interesting-theorem-in-insert-subject-here/2431#comment2259_2431`.  So, although the 'native' URL includes both comment number _and_ question number, the question number is irrelevant?  (Also [asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1197777) in your other post.  Link to [@rene's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1197769).)